# Is it possible to remove an element in a vector in C?

Tags: c, function, vector

I've a problem with an exercise. It asks "Write a function that gets a vector and returns the vector removing any prime numbers". There's also a suggestion, "Remove an i-th element in a vector means move from the i+1-th element to the (N-1)-th element to cover the empty spot left from the deleted element".
And I can't use any pointer.

I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Try a for loop starting at i.  Don't forget to decrement the variable holding the size of the array at the end!

Comment: @Arianna Tatani The passed array to the function will be already a pointer to its first element and the subscript operator is an expression with a pointer.:)

Comment: What is a vector? There is no such thing in C. There might be in a library you are using? Or it is defined in the context of your exercise? That is not just being "vocabulary-nazi" here. Since "vector" is not a standard thing in C, we can't know from this word how your "vector" of number is organized in memory. Are the elements of the "vector" in a chained list? Or a simple C "array" (array of pointer to a block of numbers, so anything indexable by `[...]`)? And if so, does the order of elements in it matter?

Comment: And indeed, hard to handle a variable number of numbers without using pointers.

Comment: I am not sure what it is you have problem with. To clarify please state whether you still would have a problem if the assignment were more clearly phrased e.g. like "Removing an i-th element in a vector means to iterate from the i+1-th element over each element between it and the (N-1)-th element (each time copying the value found in the current element to the element at the index which is one lower) to cover the empty spot left from the deleted element and end up with an empty spot at the end of the vector, which is then considered to be not part of the resulting and now shorter vector."

Comment: If that solves your problem you need to ask your teacher whether that is what they meant, because of course from me it is only a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Write a function that gets a vector

There is no such thing as a `vector` type in C. Probably it's an array.

> And I can't use any pointer

hmmm... passing an array to a function in C is actually "passing a pointer" so it will be very difficult to avoid. But the function can be written so that it kind of hides the use of a pointer.

Now for the code, the function could look like:

```
size_t remove_primes(size_t size, int a[]);
```

That is a function taking an array and it's size as arguments and returns the new size after primes has been removed.

In code it could be something like:

```
size_t remove_primes(size_t size, int a[])
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i < size)
    {
        if (is_prime(a[i]))
        {
            // It's a prime so move all element after i'th element to the left
            //
            // memmove(&a[i], &a[i+i], (size - 1 - i) * sizeof a[0]);
            //
            // or to hide use of pointers
            //
            for (size_t j = i+1; j < size; ++j) a[j-1] = a[j];

            --size;
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

or for better performance like:

```
size_t remove_primes(size_t size, int a[])
{
    size_t writer = 0;
    for (size_t reader = 0; reader < size; ++reader)
    {
        if ( ! is_prime(a[reader]))
        {
            // Not a prime so save the value
            a[writer] = a[reader];
            ++writer;
        }
    }
    return writer;
}
```